# The specified conversion is not valid. Is IDataReader buggy? Or what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, idatareader

[image]

Take a look at the image. You will see I retrieve a boolean value from the IDataReader. But calling `IdataReader..GetBoolean()` throws that error: `The specified conversion is not valid.`

While `Convert.ToBoolean(drDatosDco.GetValue(6))` works fine.

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Boolean()
at file.cs:line 54
```

The column data type in the database is `bit` with value `1`.

Comment: Take a look at the docs for `Convert.ToBoolean` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean).  It will convert a `double`, even a `DateTime` to a boolean.  If your query returns an integer, then my guess is that `Convert.ToBoolean` will return `false` for a zero-return and `true` for anything else.  However, look at the docs for `IDataRecord.GetBoolean` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.idatarecord.getboolean).  *"No conversions are performed. Therefore, the data retrieved must already be a Boolean; otherwise an exception is generated"*

Comment: Well the doc is lying. Because for some bit with value `1` it throws exception. As you can see in the picture. `GetVaue` got it right but getBoolean says it cannot convert it to  boolean.

Comment: What does your query look like? What is the type of the 7th column in the returned resultset. I'm real sure that there's no but in `SqlDataRecord.GetBoolean`

Comment: For what it's worth, I see nothing in the picture telling me that what you are saying is true.  What the picture is saying is that **a)** The value in the 7th column of the current SqlDataRecord is convertible to a `bool` using `Convert.ToBoolean`.  From the docs, that could be just about anything (like, for example, a `DateTime`).  and that **b)** that if you call `SqlDataRecord.GetBoolean` on that 7th column, it throws an exception.  From the docs, anything but a `BIT` resultset column type will throw.  Without knowing what the type of that column is, there's nothing that can be said.

Comment: You said **anything but a BIT resultset column type will throw**. I specified in the question this **The column data type in the database is bit with value 1**. The value of the `7th column in the database` is `1` and the datatype is `bit` and `not null`. To be clear, you're trying to tell me that  `SqlDataRecord.GetBoolean` throws exception when the type is a `bit`.

Comment: Just to be clear "anything but a BIT resultset column type will throw" means "a BIT will **not** throw, and a non-BIT will throw"

Comment: In that case `SqlDataRecord.GetBoolean` has a bug. Later I will update my question to show a capture of the column value and the datatype in the database.

Comment: I just whipped a program, doing a `Select *` from the old `pubs` demo database's `authors` table. The ninth column is a `BIT` named `contract`. Doing a `reader.GetBoolean(8)` on a data reader works like a charm. `SqlDataReader` underlies just about every .NET data access mechanism. It's been there since Day 1 (in 2002). I'd be very surprised if you found a bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't `IdataReader`. The table type is a `bit` but the information is coming from a `stored procedure` where they cast the `bit` to `tinyint`.
[image]

As @Flydog57 said in the comments above

> From the docs, anything but a BIT resultset column type will throw.

So the problem was the cast from the `bit` to `tinyint`.